# In angular.js, can I filter something before I $eval() it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js for a web app. I have some data I want to `$eval()`, but the problem is that before I do that, I need to replace a placeholder in the string with the name of the variable I'm using. I wrote a filter to handle that, but I can't figure out how to run the filter before the string is passed to `$eval()`.

Here's an example of what I'd like to happen:

app.js

```
$scope.newVariable=3;
$scope.test='2+[placeholder]';
```

index.html

```
<p>{{$eval(test|replace:'[placeholder]':'newVariable')}}</p>
```

What I want to happen is for '[placeholder]' to be replaced by 'newVariable' and then for that new string to be passed into `$eval()`. The way it is written now, the page just crashes when I load it. I've tested the filter separately, so I know that's not the problem. Is there a way to apply this filter before the string is `$eval()`ed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) should be invoked on a scope that you must specify.

Since filters can easily be chained in Angular, you could try creating an additional filter that will perform the evaluation on your replaced expression and then have it displayed.

For example, your filter definition could look like:

```
.filter('eval', function() {
    return function(expr, scope) {
        // Note how $eval is called for the passed in scope.
        return scope.$eval(expr);
    }
})
```

Then in your HTML:

```
{{ test | replace:'[placeholder]':'newVariable' | eval:this }}
```

Note that the `this` supplied to the `eval` filter should be the `$scope` of the controller.